# Как отсортировать через TVFilters мероприятия дата которых тоже сегодняшнего дня, часа, минуты?

Tags: modx, revo

Добрый день,
Делаю сайт на Modx Revo, не получается отфильтровать мероприятия с датой проведения позже сегодняшнего дня, мероприятия вывожу через getResurses, не выводится вообще ничего:

```
[[getResources?
&parents=`8`
&tpl=`ImmediateEvent`
&includeContent=`1`
&includeTVs=`EventDate`
&processTVs=`1`
&tvFilters=`EventDate>=[[!toDate]]`
&limit=`4444`
]]
```

Tv параметр Event Date выводит: 17.09.2016, 13:30
Снипет toDate выводит: 03.09.2016, 20:09,
сам снипет:

```
<?php
echo date("d.m.Y, H:m");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема аналогична вашему "соседнему" вопросу. Значение TV выводится на страницу через фильтр, поэтому вы его видите не таким каким оно хранится в базе, а сравнение производится в исходном формате (как в базе)